# Just like createSelector() in ngrx, is there anything like that in vuex

Tags: angular, vue.js, redux, vuex, ngrx

I know in Angular Ngrx there is CreateSelector(), I am looking something same in vuex as well. Does anyone have any idea about it or how to work like createSelector in vuex.

```
In angular: 
Export interface State {
username: string;
}

Export const initialState: State = {
username: “michael123” }

Then reducer which is same as Mutations in vuex.

Export interface Store {
actualState: State;
}

// this will return everything from the state
Export const getState = (state: Store) => state.actualState;

//Now if you need to get username from the getState
Export const getUserName = createSelector(
getState, 
(state) => state.userName
);

//now if you need to use other selector to get that’s user age from                //different store you can do this way 
//Assume this store selector have user age selctorName:getUserBio

Export cost combineUsernameWithAge = createSelector(
getUserName,
getUserBio, 
(Username, userBio) => {
return “This ” + username + “ is “ + userBio.age + “ years old”
}
);

Above is the ngrx example, can anyone know how can I do the same way in Vuex.
```

Comment: Not everyone working with Vue had been worked with angular. If you could discribe what the CreateSelector() do... You will get help from more people.

Comment: It looks kinda  like  getters - but to access a state  you either  mapState into computed or access it directly $store.state.userName https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#getters

Comment: If you look at the source code of it, it becomes clear that it's not specific to ngrx or redux, but rather that it expects an object where each key is a selector that it can then reference. no reason you can't use it with vue, too.

Comment: It’s ngrx, if you google ngrx selector you will see more of it.